# What's the Russian for "open-source"?

Tags: перевод, информатика

I would like to know how to translate 'open-source' into Russian, as well as how to properly translate 'bug' — as in a software bug.

Also, if you know of any resources for technical dictionaries or terminology, I would appreciate the reference.

Comment: I've seen "свободный доступ" in the same meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Открытое программное обеспечение](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

*Bug* in jargon is [баг](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B3). A proper translation would be "ошибка" (my guess).

Note that "debugger" would be "отладчик", but in jargon people say "debagger" :)

Answer (score 10):

In 90% of cases, if not more, programmers would use transliterated English terms. This is what I usually hear at work:

*open-source* => *опенсорс*

*bug* => *баг*

*debugger* => *дебаггер*

In writing, I would avoid using *опенсорс* and use *программное обеспечение с открытым кодом*. As regards the word *баг*, it's ok to use it in writing. I often see the word *дебагер* in writing (it's usually written with one *г*), although *отладчик* is just as common.

Comment: дебагер vs. отладчик is probably generational. Those who started programming during Soviet times will overwhelmingly use the latter in both spoken and written language, in my opinion.

Comment: @Aksakal I agree. In old books (published 10-20 years ago) I always see *отладчик*. But I think I have never heard *отладчик* at work, only *дебаггер*.

Answer (score 4):

I would say "ПО с открытым исходным кодом".

Answer (score 0):

Открытое программное обеспечение 
*or*
Программное обеспечение с открытым исходным кодом
*context is not important*